# Программa склонения по падежам

Tags: грамматика, общие-вопросы, склонение

Добро пожаловать!
Я написал программу склонения по падежам в русском языке: http://aztekium.pl/skloneniye.py?lang=ru К сожалению я плохо владею русским языком и я не уверен, склоняет ли моя программа
правильно. Если какое-то слово неправильно склоняется, тогда, пожалуйста, напишите мне майл: aztekium@op.pl сообщая какое это слово и как оно должно правильно склоняться. Спасибо за Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Очень оригинально... Делаю то, не знаю что. Не знаю, что такое склонение, не умею склонять, но делаю. А как вы предполагаете, мы должны Вам помочь? Набирать каждое слово по очереди и отслеживать правильность - неправильность? Не слишком ли трудоемкая помощь получается? Я зашла по ссылке, набрала слово "ясли", вроде все правильно, но сидеть и набирать слова скучно и неинтересно.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы верно склонять слова, нужно иметь базу данных с парадигмами словоизменения. У Вас, похоже, работает какой-то алгоритм. У меня в программе ( http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe ) есть аналогичный, но для каждого слова, отсутствующего в базовом словаре, строится дерево вариантов (от единиц до десятков), из которого пользователь, возжелавший занести новое слово в свой личный словарик, должен сделать выбор, основываясь на своём знании русского языка. В интернете есть много ресурсов, предоставляющих доступ к полным, выверенным, авторитетным словарям словоизменения.

Зачем нужен Ваш ресурс, безграмотный даже в оформлении ("Программа во время строительства.")? Хотя бы написали, что исходное слово должно быть существительным в именительном падеже... Если это не так, то без вариантов для выбора не обойтись. Подумайте над введением в интерфейс Вашей странички признаков рода существительного и одушевлённости/неодушевлённости. Для исходного слова в именительном падеже с этими параметрами вариантов результата существенно меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю проблемы.
Берете любой электронный словарь с открытой базой, где указана тем или иным образом парадигма склонения, генерируете на его основании все падежи - и сраниваете со своим алгоритмом.

Хотя я не понимаю, зачем вообще сейчас "алгоритм", если сама компактная база тянет какие-то смешные мегабайты.

Я лет тридцать назад делал что-то подобное, тогда это было актуально, счет на килобайты шел....

Comment: Алгоритм нужен в двух случаях:   
1) если слова нет в базе;   
2) если человек хочет создать нечто не очень качественное, служащее заменителем поиска по базе.